# change color and font size of HTML with PHP class

Tags: php, function, class

I need to write class that inherits (extends) my Colored class.
In the new class the text can have different font sizes in addition to different colors. The font size should set by a setter. It must be validated to be an integer between 10 and 24 otherwise an error message is thrown.
My color class works great, but my font size doesn't, someone can help ?

```php
    class coloredHtmal extends Htmalpage {
        protected $color = 'red';
        public function __set($property,$value){
            if($property == 'color'){ 
                $colors = array('blue','yellow','green','black','pink','gray','gold');
                if(in_array($value,$colors)){ 
                    $this->color = $value; 
                }
                else {
                    die("Please select one of the allowed colors");
                }
            }
        }
        public function view(){
            echo "<html>
                    <head>
                    <title> $this->title</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                    <p style = 'color:$this->color'>$this->body</p>
                    </body>
                </html>";
           }
    }

    class fontSizeHtmal extends coloredHtmal {
        protected $fontsize = '10';
        public function __set($property,$value){
            if($property == 'fontsize'){ 
                $fontsizes = array('10','11','12');
                if(in_array($value,$fontsizes)){ 
                    $this->fontsize = $value; 
                }
                else {
                    die("Please select one of the allowed font size");
                }
            }
        }
        public function view(){
            echo "<html>
                    <head>
                    <title> $this->title</title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                    <p style = 'font-size:$this->fontsize'>$this->body</p>
                    </body>
                </html>";
           }
    }
```

this is an example, just for testing the class on 10,11,12 font sizes

I test this with a simple html code (php)

```php
<?php
    include "htmalpage.php";
?>
<?php
    $hml = new coloredHtmal("[title goes here]","[body goes here]");
    $hml->color = 'green';
    $hml->fontsize = '5';
    $hml->view();
?>
```

Comment: How did you test this? (And why `Htmal`?)

Comment: ```Htmal``` because that's the name my teacher asked for

Comment: Your class `coloredHtmal` knows nothing about `fontsize`. You might have gotten something wrong about `extends`/class inheritance. If class B extends class A, class B inherits stuff from class A, not the other way. https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php. You'd need to change `$hml = new coloredHtmal(..)` to `$hml = new fontSizeHtmal(..)`

Comment: @kerbholz Didn't notice that i havn't change that part, thanks!
one last question, if i enter wrong color and wrong font size, only the font size die message is displayed and if i enter wrong color and correct font size it works, why?

Comment: Your `public function __set()`  from class `fontSizeHtmal` overwrites the `public function __set()` from its parent class `coloredHtmal`. Same for `public function view()`

Comment: @kerbholz Can i do something else? i was asked to use __set() in both class